Location access via internet sharing
I have an iPhone connected to a MacBook via USB.  The phone is on airplane mode and has Wi-Fi turned off but my computer is sharing internet.  I've confirmed the internet connection but even with location services turned on the phone can't get its location.
Is there a way for the phone to get its location via the shared internet?  For reasons, I'd rather not connect the phone to the Wi-Fi network.
